# Updating a list of matplotlib.patches.Rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having issues updating a list of size N that contains objects of Rectangles from matplotlib. What i did was I created a dummy rectangle and created a list of N dummy rectangles. I then wanted to iterate through the loop to change each index's x,y width and height. The first loop iteration shows that the values were changing but when i iterate the same list in a second loop, the values only show attributes that were left off on the final iteration in the first loop (example output shown below).

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

N = 5
dummyRect = Rectangle((None, None), None, None)
patches = [dummyRect] * N

for i in xrange(N):
    x0 = (int(np.random.randint(25, size = 1)))
    y0 = (int(np.random.randint(25, size = 1)))

    w = (int(np.random.randint(10, size = 1)) + 1) # avoiding zeroes
    h = (int(np.random.randint(10, size = 1)) + 1)

    print "Index: %s, x0: %s, y0: %s, w: %s, h: %s" % (i, x0, y0, w, h)

    patches[i].set_x(x0)
    patches[i].set_y(y0)
    patches[i].set_width(w)
    patches[i].set_height(h)

    print "XY:%s, Width: %s, Height: %s" % (patches[i].get_xy(), patches[i].get_width(), patches[i].get_height())
    print

print "__________________________________"    
for x in patches:
    print "XY:%s, Width: %s, Height: %s" % (x.get_xy(), x.get_width(), x.get_height())
```

Output:

```
Index: 0, x0: 9, y0: 21, w: 4, h: 3
XY:(9, 21), Width: 4, Height: 3

Index: 1, x0: 9, y0: 24, w: 1, h: 7
XY:(9, 24), Width: 1, Height: 7

Index: 2, x0: 4, y0: 23, w: 7, h: 1
XY:(4, 23), Width: 7, Height: 1

Index: 3, x0: 4, y0: 20, w: 3, h: 9
XY:(4, 20), Width: 3, Height: 9

Index: 4, x0: 2, y0: 13, w: 1, h: 9
XY:(2, 13), Width: 1, Height: 9

__________________________________
XY:(2, 13), Width: 1, Height: 9
XY:(2, 13), Width: 1, Height: 9
XY:(2, 13), Width: 1, Height: 9
XY:(2, 13), Width: 1, Height: 9
XY:(2, 13), Width: 1, Height: 9
```

As you can see, the output has the values from the last iteration in the first loop. Anyone know what am I doing wrong here? The same concept would work in Java, I believe but maybe not in Python?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not creating 5 different rectangles with `patches = [dummyRect] * N`, but just 5 references to the same `Rectangle` (your `dummyRect`)

You could create 5 new instances like this

```
N=5
patches = [Rectangle((None, None), None, None) for i in range(N)]
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: For posterity: it looks like this doesn't work anymore (at least on `1.5.1`), where a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number` is raised when passing `None`.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly because your list `patches` contains `N` copies of the *same* `Rectangle` patch, not independent patches. Try initializing your list with independently-created objects instead of references to the same one:

```
patches = []
for i in range(N):
    patches.append(Rectangle((None, None), None, None))
```

Comment: Your explanation helped me understand where i went wrong.Thanks for the help.